# About an app that know the Google rankings and a proxy

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

I have installed an application to know the Google rankings of my websites. I have a list with keywords like "windows spain", "windows france", etc, so for a each keyword this app sends a request to Google search.

Since I have a big list of keywords, I have problems with those requests to get the position of the website, becasuse Google thinks I am a kind of spammer or bot.

To fix this and don't have more problems, the documentation of the app says:

> Hide your IP address behind a proxy server (Preferences -> Proxy
>   Settings) so the temporary block will no longer apply.

So I go to `Preferences > Proxy settings` in my app and I get this popup:

[image]

What should I do?

I have Ubuntu and a plain ADSL internet connection.

You can see the rest of the doc page [here](http://www.link-assistant.com/support/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/57/3/search-engines-stopped-processing-my-requests-what-is-a-temporary-block).

Comment: > becasuse Google thinks Im a kind of spammer or bot < ..... aren't you a bot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take advantage of this, you need to use a service that provides proxy serving.

Each of your requests will get sent to the proxy service, and they will carry out the request on your behalf.  Often they have multiple nodes so that requests can come from different IP addresses and so look less spammy to Google.

These services are usually paid for, and will readily come up in a Google search.

Comment: At the beginning I thought that I simply had to install a proxy in my computer. But after reading your words, I understand it is something I have to pay for, is that right?

Comment: If you install a proxy on your machine, it would work, in the sense that you could forward your requests through it.  However, those requests would still originate from your IP (as it is inside your network) and so would not solve the problem.  Yes, you normally have to pay for a proxy service.